Oracle Flashback queries for massively-parallel scanning of a large distributed table
I'd like to perform a massive parallel scanning of a large table in a clustered Oracle database setup (with a master node and several replicas). All client transactions that read from the table need to see a consistent view of it. From what I can see, this can be done using flashback queries. However, I'm not sure if these queries can be addressed to the different cluster nodes while maintaining the consistency of the table's data.
Could you please confirm whether this approach is correct?

On a master node:

SELECT current_scn FROM database;


On replica 1:

SELECT * FROM table WHERE key >= 0 AND key < K1 AS OF $captured scn; 


On replica 2:

SELECT * FROM table WHERE key >= K1 AND key < K2 AS OF $captured scn; 


What do you mean by 'replica'? Is it a dataguard? ....

Or is this a standard Real Application Cluster (RAC) setup? If so, the "shared everything" architecture means that all nodes contain the same data and will return the same results.
